# How can I use RestClient to automatically resolve hostname to localhost and local port as it is happening in TestRestTemplate?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

My integration tests are currently using `TestRestTemplate` and I would like to use new and shiny `RestClient` instead.

When I try to replace:

```java
testRestTemplate.getForEntity("/actuator/health", String.class);
```

with

```java
RestClient restClient = RestClient.create(testRestTemplate.getRestTemplate());
restClient.get().uri("/actuator/health").retrieve().toEntity(String.class);
```

it complains about missing hostname. How can I overcome that?

Comment: You have to prefix your request uri with the base url, http-server, port. Does this work?

Comment: I want to keep ommited hostname and port (especially this one: I use random free port).

Comment: Get it from testRestTemplate? `testRestTemplate.getUriTemplateHandler().expand("/").getHost()` & `getPort()`